# EPIRequestException when I try to connect with my terminal

Tags: terminal, connection, cics

I´m trying to create a terminal to connect with EPI in CICS Transaction Gateway.  My code is below.  When the connect() method exectues, an exception is generated.

> com.ibm.ctg.epi.EPIRequestException: CTG6799E Código de retorno
>   EPI_ERR_FAILED de la llamada EPIRequest.addExTerminal at
>   com.ibm.ctg.epi.Terminal.flowConnect(Unknown Source) at
>   com.ibm.ctg.epi.Terminal.connect(Unknown Source) at
>   MainEpi.main(MainEpi.java:32)

The CICS TG server is running on an AIX node, I tried generating the basic terminal and the extended terminal but anyone can connect.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.ibm.ctg.client.EPIRequest;
import com.ibm.ctg.client.JavaGateway;
import com.ibm.ctg.epi.*;

public class MainEpi {

    public MainEpi() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        try {
            EPIGateway epiGate = new EPIGateway("tcp://10.191.104.244", 48620);

            Terminal term = new Terminal();
            term.setGateway(epiGate);
            term.setServerName("CTGDES");
            term.connect();
            System.out.println("Conexión establecida con la terminal");


            epiGate.close();

        }catch(EPIException ep) {
            ep.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you include the exception ?

Comment: Sorry, i forget it, the exception is this : com.ibm.ctg.epi.EPIRequestException: CTG6799E Código de retorno EPI_ERR_FAILED de la llamada EPIRequest.addExTerminal
 at com.ibm.ctg.epi.Terminal.flowConnect(Unknown Source)
 at com.ibm.ctg.epi.Terminal.connect(Unknown Source)
 at MainEpi.main(MainEpi.java:32)

Comment: Line 32 is not in the program, do you have a stack trace that matches the code above?

Comment: It's the same i ran it again and it referes to close of the last catch (IOExeption)